# Refurbished Acer AMD A10-7800 Desktop

Tags: desktop

[Acer Aspire ATC-220-EB52 Desktop](http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=7_158&item_id=099743) (Refurbished)
- AMD A10-7800 3.5GHz
- 8GB DDR3
- 1TB HDD
- AMD Radeon R7 Graphic
- Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- CAD$ 409 + 13% tax

I am considering this for a general purpose desktop + Adobe Lightroom use. Will add an SSD to speed up. Thoughts?

My current Adobe Lightroom computer is a Mid 2013 MacBook Air and it works reasonable well. The [CPU](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=1944&cmp%5B%5D=2262) & Graphics in the AMD A10 is better so the overall performance should be better (assuming Windows & Mac versions are similar).

Is this line of thinking accurate? Happy for alternatives or even a build recommendation within the same budget. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about refurb PCs, but building your on PC tends to give you better performance at a lower price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for another option, here's a build using an Intel CPU. Personally, I'm not a big fan of AMD CPUs, I haven't had a good experience with them. [Here's the link to the PC part picker list.](http://pcpartpicker.com/list/kdYfhq) Again, everthing's off Amazon. I'd personally go with this Intel build over the AMD build I mentioned. The i3 6100 has a benchmark that is slightly above/better than the AMD A10 7800. Regardless, both these builds should do what you need.

**CPU**: Intel Core i3-6100 3.7GHz Dual-Core Processor  ($126.28 @ Amazon)

**Motherboard**: MSI B150M Pro-VD Micro ATX LGA1151 Motherboard  ($60.54 @ Amazon)

**Memory**: Crucial 8GB (1 x 8GB) DDR4-2133 Memory  ($41.99 @ Amazon)

**Storage**: Seagate Barracuda 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive  ($47.99 @ Amazon)

**Case**: Rosewill Galaxy-03 ATX Mid Tower Case  ($29.99 @ Amazon)

**Power Supply**: CoolMax 400W ATX Power Supply  ($23.22 @ Amazon)

**Other**: Windows 10 Home 64 Bit OEM DVD ENGLISH  ($75.99 @ Amazon)

### **Total**: $406.00

Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available

Comment: Agree the Intel CPU is better. Will price it out at the local computer store and see what I get in Canadian dollars with taxes. Thank you.

Comment: How about this? http://ca.pcpartpicker.com/user/richsu/saved/bqnYcf

Comment: @RichardHsu Looks good, as far as I can tell. You may need a SATA cable for the hard drive, but usually 1 or 2 are included with the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make a "identical" build, that matches the specs you mentioned. [Here's the link to the PC part picker](http://pcpartpicker.com/list/mNTF4C). Everything is off Amazon.com

**CPU**: AMD A10-7800 3.5GHz Quad-Core Processor  ($123.00 @ Amazon)

**Motherboard**: MSI A68HM-E33 V2 Micro ATX FM2+ Motherboard  ($49.99 @ Amazon)

**Memory**: Kingston 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory  ($41.55 @ Amazon)

**Storage**: Seagate Barracuda 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive  ($47.99 @ Amazon)

**Case**: Rosewill FBM-02 MicroATX Mini Tower Case  ($28.91 @ Amazon)

**Power Supply**: CoolMax 400W ATX Power Supply  ($23.22 @ Amazon)

**Other**: Windows 10 Home 64 Bit OEM DVD ENGLISH  ($75.99 @ Amazon)

### **Total: $390.65**

Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available.

Comment: If I remove Windows 10 (which I don't need), it will make this a better deal. Will price this out too at the local computer store. Thank you.